# Enumerate item label position by even/odd page

Tags: lists, positioning, koma-script, enumitem, double-sided

I have a KOMA-script two-sided document and an `enumerate` environment (from package `enumitem`) which item labels are outside of the text body.

What I want is that all item labels are on the outer page side, so for odd pages on the right side of the text.

Consider below MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\newenvironment{enumerateWithCode}[1]
{%
    \begin{enumerate}[
        leftmargin=0em,
        label={\small\textbf{#1.\arabic*)}},
        ref=#1.\arabic*]
}{%
    \end{enumerate}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerateWithCode}{RIGHT}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerateWithCode}
\clearpage
\begin{enumerateWithCode}{LEFT}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerateWithCode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the environment option `labelsep=\theEnumerateWithCodeLabelSep` with

```
\newcommand{\theEnumerateWithCodeLabelSep}{%
    \dimexpr -5.5em -\textwidth\relax%
}
```

does move the item label to the right side (due to `-\textwidth`) but would mean I have to manually place separate environments whenever the item list expands multiple pages.

[image]

Therefore I have tried to use KOMA-scripts `\Ifthispageodd`

```
\newcommand{\theEnumerateWithCodeLabelSep}{%
    \Ifthispageodd{%
        \dimexpr -5.5em -\textwidth\relax%
    }{%
        .5em%
    }%
}
```

and package `ifoddpage`

```
\newcommand{\theEnumerateWithCodeLabelSep}{%
    \checkoddpage%
    \ifoddpage%
    \dimexpr -5.5em -\textwidth\relax%
    \else%
    .5em%
    \fi%
}
```

to dynamically/conditionally define the labelsep value with no success due to compilation errors.

Note: Whenever this may works out, I would also like to control the label to change the used braces.

**FINAL SOLUTION** based on accepted answer of user691586

Using labels without braces to make them work on even and odd pages and having them of same text length to provide somewhat equal spacing to the text body

```
\newcommand{\theEnumerateWithCodeLabelSep}{%
    \Ifthispageodd{\labelsep\dimexpr -2.1em -\labelwidth -\textwidth\relax}%
                  {\labelsep -.25em}%
}
% hacky solution for left and right alignment working on even and odd pages
\SetLabelAlign{enumerateWithCodeAlign}{\hss\llap{#1}\hfil} 
\newenvironment{enumerateWithCode}[1]
{%
    \let\originalitem\item%
    \def\item{%
        \Needspace*{\baselineskip}%
        \theEnumerateWithCodeLabelSep%
        \originalitem%
    }%
    \begin{enumerate}[
        leftmargin=0em,
        align=enumerateWithCodeAlign,
        label={\small\textbf{#1.\arabic*}},
        ref=#1.\arabic*] %% or \alph*
}{%
    \end{enumerate}%
    \def\item{\originalitem}%
}
```

Comment: This is a problem of expandability. The labelsep must clearly be usable in a TeX dimension assignment, and you need an expandable way of checking for page oddness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See code comments

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{needspace}
\newcommand{\updatelabelsep}{%
    \Ifthispageodd{\labelsep\dimexpr\itemindent-\labelwidth-\linewidth\relax}%
                  {\labelsep 0.5em}%
}
\newenvironment{enumerateWithCode}[1]
{%
    % maybe safe as long as not using * variants (inline) of enumerate
    \let\originalitem\item
    \def\item{\par
            % make sure this item has room, if not clear page while
            % keeping flushbottom in effect, so that the reference
            % inserted by \Ifthispageodd will be at top of next page
            % and the test of page parity on second LaTeX pass will be ok
            \Needspace*{\baselineskip}% maybe .5\baselineskip actually enough
            \updatelabelsep
            \originalitem
            }%
    \begin{enumerate}[%
        leftmargin=0em,
        label={\small\textbf{#1.\arabic*)}},
        ref=#1.\arabic*,
        labelwidth=6em,% make it large enough
        % itemindent=2em, % only to test
        ]
}{%
    \end{enumerate}%
}

\begin{document}
Skip to bottom
\vspace*{\dimexpr\textheight-4\baselineskip\relax}
\begin{enumerateWithCode}{ABCDE}
    \item random text
    \item random text
    \item random text
    \item random text
    \item random text
    \item random text
\end{enumerateWithCode}

\end{document}
```

[image: list with page breaks and labels in margins]

#### (obsolete first and second versions)

(second version, slightly better)

Try this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\newcommand{\updatelabelsep}{%
    \Ifthispageodd{\labelsep\dimexpr -5.5em -\textwidth\relax}%
                  {\labelsep .5em }%
}
\newenvironment{enumerateWithCode}[1]
{%
    \begin{enumerate}[%
        leftmargin=0em,
        label={\small\textbf{#1.\arabic*)}},
        ref=#1.\arabic*,
        ]
}{%
    \end{enumerate}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerateWithCode}{ABCDE}
    \updatelabelsep\item \lipsum[1]
    \updatelabelsep\item \lipsum[1]
    \updatelabelsep\item \lipsum[1]
    \updatelabelsep\item \lipsum[1]
    \updatelabelsep\item \lipsum[1]
    \updatelabelsep\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerateWithCode}
\clearpage
\begin{enumerateWithCode}{FGHIJ}
    \updatelabelsep\item \lipsum[1]
    \updatelabelsep\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerateWithCode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to have to add manually `\updatelabelsep` you can try this near end of preamble:

```latex
\let\originalitem\item
\def\item{\updatelabelsep\originalitem}
```

Then remove all occurrences of `\updatelabelsep` in the code above.

This looked a priori a bit dangerous (I see two `\let\item\enit@endinbox` in `enumitem` source code and did not search through this code extensively), but at least here appears to work. Use at own risk.

(initial answer)

Try this

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
%\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newdimen\mydimen
\newenvironment{enumerateWithCode}[1]
{%
    \Ifthispageodd{\mydimen \dimexpr -5.5em -\textwidth\relax}%
                  {\mydimen .5em }%
    \begin{enumerate}[%
        leftmargin=0em,
        label={\small\textbf{#1.\arabic*)}},
        ref=#1.\arabic*,
        labelsep=\mydimen
        ]
}{%
    \end{enumerate}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerateWithCode}{RIGHT}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerateWithCode}
\clearpage
\begin{enumerateWithCode}{LEFT}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerateWithCode}

\end{document}
```

I presume `\Ifthispageodd` does not work purely by expansion so it could not be used as `labelsep` key value as this would end-up in some dimen (or skip, not checked) assignment by enumitem.  So I use it before actually calling the enumitem environment.

Attention though that in case of multiple items there it is parity of page where environment starts which counts.

To fix this, one probably can do this but would need to presumably enter into details of how enumitem implements labelsep; which I did not do to avoid too hacky solution.

(end of obsolete versions)

Comment: But with this code, you still have to separate items to two different lists, if a list would expand multiple pages, wouldn't you?

Comment: @cabohah visiting the site only 11 minutes after your comment! Yes you are right, as I already pointed in my answer.  However one can reset manually before each item. I will edit. Next step would be to find a hook point into `enumitem`'s `\item` which I will not do (lack of time).

Comment: @cabohah well I will have to look into `\item` because resetting the `labelsep` before`\item` does not have effect. It is too late `enumitem` has already frozen the thing.

Comment: Nevertheless your basic idea was good. I've extended it a little bit (see my answer).

Comment: @cabohah ah ok did not see it before posting my updated one..

Comment: The parity detection in my answer via Koma `\Ifthispageodd` i s probably a bit fragile because it is done before the paragraph (with its label inserted via `\everypar`) starts and TeX decides to move or not to next page.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help guys.
FYI: I have placed the override part of ```\item``` within the ```\newenvironment```, so before ```\begin{enumerate}``` und a reset (```\def\item{\originalitem}```) after ```\end{enumerate}```.

I do have some places were ```\Ifthispageodd``` seems to be wrong, but i have no problem to manually search for these and try to figure out some command to force the correct ```\labelsep`` on them.

Comment: I have changed the labelsep for odd pages to include ```-\labelwidth``` so i can set the spacing to match the even pages, result is: ```-.5em -\labelwidth -\textwidth```.

It would work great if I also had an expandable ```\Ifthispageodd``` to set the ```align``` option (maybe with ```\SetLabelAlign``` from the package) to be ```right``` on odd pages.
May you guys have an idea for that?

Comment: FYI: An manual workaround for those wrong placed labels I have is to override the ```\updatelabelsep``` definition on such items, so that is it not conditionally. Following forces the even page case e.g.: ```{\renewcommand\updatelabelsep{\labelsep .5em}\item ... }```

Comment: @ToTenTiger see updated answer